# Split string between two characters in C#

Tags: c#, split

How do you split a string between two characters?

I need to split a string between all occurrences of '┐' and '└'.

Sample String:

```
┐1  1.26582  0.0088└┐1  1.26682  0.0093└┐1  1.26922  0.0089└┐1  1.27172  0.0084└
```

Required Format:

```
┐1  1.26582  0.0088└
┐1  1.26682  0.0093└
┐1  1.26922  0.0089└
┐1  1.27172  0.0084└
```

Comment: You have given a requirement but not a question.

Comment: Use Split('┐'), I guess?

Comment: @GrantWinney: He doesn't want to split _by_ two characters but _between_ two.

Answer (score 2):

**Tried & Tested**

```
string input = "┐1 1.26582 0.0088└┐1 1.26682 0.0093└┐1 1.26922 0.0089└┐1 1.27172 0.0084└";
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[└])");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
┐1 1.26582 0.0088└ 

┐1 1.26682 0.0093└

┐1 1.26922 0.0089└

┐1 1.27172 0.0084└
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, Can you help me on this?<br/>

This is my Code:<br/>

Data = Port1.ReadExisting();<br/>
display.Invoke(new Action(() =><br/>
{<br/>
display.AppendText(Data);<br/>
}));<br/>
com.CommandText = "insert into RawData (datetime,data) values('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','" + Data + "')";<br/>
com.ExecuteNonQuery();<br/>
<br/>
Problem is data comes as a series, what I need to do is split data like ┐1 1.26582 0.0088└

Comment: sorry didnt understood your query

Comment: Can I have ur skype or email?

Comment: arijitmukherjee1988@gmail.com/skype is erarijit

Answer (score 1):

Use regular-expressions:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("┐(.*?)└");
var matches = regex.Matches("┐1 1.26582 0.0088└┐1 1.26682 0.0093└┐1 1.26922 0.0089└┐1 1.27172 0.0084└");
foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Result:

```
┐1 1.26582 0.0088└ 
┐1 1.26682 0.0093└
┐1 1.26922 0.0089└
┐1 1.27172 0.0084└
```

Comment: Hi Tim, check my code as well and comment

Comment: Thanks for the respond, Can you help me on this?This is my Code: Data = Port1.ReadExisting(); display.Invoke(new Action(() => display.AppendText(Data); })); com.CommandText = "insert into RawData (datetime,data) values('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','" + Data + "')"; com.ExecuteNonQuery(); Problem is data comes as a series, what I need to do is split data like ┐1 1.26582 0.0088└

Answer (score 0):

Despite the poorly-asked question, I do think the question of how to split *between* characters rather than on them is at least a little interesting.

It can be done easily with regex, but keeping with just C#, a quick-and-dirty LINQ pattern would be:

```
public static string[] SplitAfter(this string str, char splitter)
{
    return str.Split(splitter).Skip(1).Select(s => splitter + s).ToArray();
}
```

So in order:

- Split on the character
- Remove the empty result before the first instance of the character
- Add back in the splitter character that was removed by `Split`

In the OP's case, this would be called like:

```
var result = "┐1 1.26582 0.0088└┐1 1.26682 0.0093└┐1 1.26922 0.0089└┐1 1.27172 0.0084└".SplitAfter('┐');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try : yourString.Split('└'), and then add └ to every element of the returned array, because you will lose them with Split.

Comment: it will not include the delimiter :(